# Write an async coroutine that's python 2 and 3 compatible

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

Normally to write python 2/3 compatible code you follow a certain style that can be understood by both interpreters, for example: https://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html.

However, because asyncio introduces syntax such as `async def` and `await function()`, this will cause a parse error if run under Python 2.

How can you write a library that is python 2 and python 3 compatible that can still provide an asyncio interface? If there is no easy way to do this, is it possible to make a certain async submodule in the library that can only be imported in python 3.5+?

Comment: Do you have any specific reason to support legacy Python (end of life is in less then a year from now https://pythonclock.org). I probably wouldn't build a new library (especially async) with Python 2 and Python <= 3.4 and focus on supported and current versions.

Comment: If you do want to support older versions you'd have to avoid using async/await and do with threading/eventlet or implement async coroutines with generators/yield statements.

Comment: It's not for a new library, it's for an existing library that supports 2&3. But in any case the problem still exists for libraries that want to support any version of Python 3.

Comment: Are async generators not deprecated? Will they still work in future versions of Python 3? If so, would you mind writing up an answer, because that's probably my solution

Comment: You could always implement your own scheduler/event-loop but I wouldn't recommend it. I'm not sure what your usecase is but if applicable I'd probably look into greenlet/gevent, if you want true parallelism multiprocessing is the way to go.

Comment: Async generators are only available in Python 3.6 and later and are definitely not deprecated. Ordinary generators are available in both Python 2 and 3 and are also not deprecated. What is deprecated is the usage of generators to implement coroutines, i.e. the `@asyncio.coroutine` decorator. But even that kind of generator heavily depends on the `yield from` keyword and on the `asyncio` framework, neither of which was never available in Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

Supporting asyncio-style coroutines in Python 2 is not possible because Python 2 has none of:

- `async def` and `await`;
- Their predecessor `yield from`;
- The asyncio library itself, in any shape or form.

There was a project to create a Python 2 version of asyncio using ordinary generators without `yield from`, but it was [abandoned](https://github.com/vstinner/trollius) years ago.

Comment: In that case, what about my second question: "Is it possible to make a certain async submodule in the library that can only be imported in python 3.5+?"

Comment: @Miguel Sure, there's nothing magical about async submodules.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not feasible to support `async def` functions in Python 2, it is *possible* to create a module which includes `async def` functions that are only imported in Python 3.5 or later.  But!  ***There are likely better ways of solving this such as putting asyncio code in a different module, package, or completely separate library.***

The example below falls squarely into the category of, "***Yes you can, but why would you?***"  Naïve testing indicates it can run on CPython 2.6.9 to 3.7.3, with the asyncio code only being loaded on 3.5 or later.

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import sys


ASYNC_SOURCE = """
import asyncio

async def three():
    print('three') 
"""
if sys.version_info[0] > 2 and sys.version_info[1] > 4:
    exec(compile(ASYNC_SOURCE, __file__, "exec"))


def two():
    print("two")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    two()
    if "three" in locals():
        asyncio.run(three())
```