# Should I trust pip's "Successfully installed..."?

Tags: python, pip

In brief, `pip -vvv install apy` reports "Successfully installed ..." even though the verbose output shows that Python fails to compile some of the installed files.

Below are the last lines of the output from `pip -vvv install apy` (I have removed some blank lines to reduce the listing's height):

```
... 
  Compiling /tmp/ankivenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/asyncfilters.py ...
    File "/tmp/ankivenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/asyncfilters.py", line 8
      async def auto_to_seq(value):
              ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  
  Compiling /tmp/ankivenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/asyncsupport.py ...
    File "/tmp/ankivenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/asyncsupport.py", line 18
      async def concat_async(async_gen):
              ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  changing mode of /tmp/ankivenv/bin/flask to 775

Successfully installed Jinja2-2.11.3 MarkupSafe-1.1.1 Werkzeug-1.0.1 apy-0.2.3 click-7.1.2 flask-1.1.4 httplib2-0.19.1 itsdangerous-1.1.0 oauth2-1.9.0.post1 pyparsing-2.4.7
Removed build tracker: '/tmp/pip-req-tracker-3_mlWH'
```

Furthermore, after getting the results shown above, I confirmed that `python` indeed cannot compile the installed versions of the files mentioned in the error messages above.  For example:

```
python -m py_compile /tmp/ankivenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/asyncfilters.py
  File "/tmp/ankivenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/asyncfilters.py", line 8
    async def auto_to_seq(value):
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

---

**Q:** Is this a bug in the version of `pip` I am using?  Or are the errors shown above indeed negligible?

---

The version of `pip` I am using for this is 20.3.4, in accordance with the recommendations given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/65871131 .  (This is all running under Python 2.7.16.)

If anyone is interested, below I give a `bash` script that reproduces the results described above.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

MYVENV=/tmp/ankivenv

deactivate 2>/dev/null
rm -rf "$MYVENV"

export PYTHONWARNINGS=ignore:DEPRECATION

virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python2 "$MYVENV" || exit $?
source "$MYVENV/bin/activate" || exit $?

##################################################################
# based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/65871131 ##################
curl -sO https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py || return $?
python get-pip.py || return $?
python -m pip install --upgrade 'pip < 21.0' || return $?
##################################################################

pip -vvv install apy
```

Comment: `async` is not supported in 2.7, which is why you're seeing invalid syntax https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54023021/write-an-async-coroutine-thats-python-2-and-3-compatible.

Comment: The errors occured during compiling .py files to bytecode .pyc files. Such errors are probably ignored, relying on the fact the interpreter creates missing .pyc automatically.